# MongoDB returns object reference not set to instance of object

Tags: c#, mongodb

The below code returns results if it finds an exact match in mongodb database , however the below code throws "object reference not set to an instance" when no record match is found in database.

```
string retailerinfoCollection = oDatabaseEntities.retailerinfoCollection;      
        IMongoCollection<Retailers> retailerList = db.GetCollection<Retailers>(retailerinfoCollection);
        var retailerinfo = await retailerList.Find(p=> p.retailername == oreceiptData.RetailerName).SingleAsync();
```

Is this the desired MongoDB behavior ? What is the best recommended approach to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` to avoid null exception at runtime.

if there is no record found then it will return the default value of that type.

Read this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/first-firstordefault-single-singleordefault-in-c-sharp) to get better understanding about Single and singleOrDefault